# Android Packaging Failed, NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, android, deployment, build, mono

```
      C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Novell\mandroid.exe -v --nosign --sdk-dir="C:\android-sdk-windows" --builddir="C:\dotnetdev\MapDroid\obj\Debug\android" --framework-dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2" --framework-dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0" -S="C:\dotnetdev\MapDroid\obj\Debug\res" --package="MapDroid.MapDroid"   --nolink --abi="armeabi" --java-sdk-dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26" --debug --manifest-template="C:\dotnetdev\MapDroid\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" --sdk-platform="8" "C:\dotnetdev\MapDroid\bin\Debug\MapDroid.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2\Mono.Android.dll" "C:\dotnetdev\MonoMap\bin\Debug\MonoMap.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" 
monodroid : error 1: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object [C:\dotnetdev\MapDroid\MapDroid.csproj]
    at MonoDroid.Utils.ProcessRocks+<ReadStandardOutput>c__Iterator5.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Monodroid.Toolbox.InvokeCommand (IEnumerable`1 commandLine) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Monodroid.Toolbox.InvokeAapt (System.String packageName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Monodroid.Droidinator.CreatePackagedResources (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 javaTypes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Monodroid.Droidinator.CreateApk () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Monodroid.MainClass.Main (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Done Building Project "C:\dotnetdev\MapDroid\MapDroid.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

This is what I thought was the most pertinent section of the build log, especially...

```
error 1: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object [C:\dotnetdev\MapDroid\MapDroid.csproj]
```

Any Ideas why this is happening?

If I just run a build, it completes successfully, but errors in packaging for the device...

Using Mono for Android

***I've also Updated to include the full Build Output -->*** http://pastie.org/2044724

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using the free version of MonoDroid, you won't be able to package, sign and deploy directly to the device from inside VS. I guess that the last line contains the source of the error.
Otherwise, I see that Newtonsoft.Json.Silverlight could not be found by the build engine.
If the app runs on the emulator, this is a confirmation of the nature of the 1st problem.